# Show Console.WriteLine output in Debug window of JetBrain's Rider IDE

Tags: console, visual-studio-debugging, rider

I have a C# WPF project that uses `System.Console.WriteLine` for debugging and in Visual Studio we can see the output in Output window.

I would like to move to JetBrain's Rider, but the `Console` output is not shown in the Debug Output window, unlike the output from `System.Diagnostics.Debug`.

I understand that I should've used `System.Diagnostics` to begin with and would be willing to brute force replace all calls in my code, but I'm wondering, if there is a setting in Rider that could spare me the hassle ...and discussions with colleagues ;o).

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I overlooked the WPF part, sorry about that. With WPF, I can confirm your observed behavior. Seems like a bug to me, maybe contact the JB support: https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=97145

Comment: Actually, I think JB's implementation is correct and Visual Studio's behavior is wrong, although practical.